# Use of "this" in ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am looking at a component of [Angular UI Tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree). The specific code I am looking at is:

`<a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;">`

The line all makes perfect sense to me, except for the use of `this` for the ng-click. I am familiar with the use of `this` in Javascript and how it differs from the use of `self` in classical OO. But I am wondering what exactly is being referred to when passed to this function call?

The code is contained in this [basic example](http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example).

Comment: It should be the current scope. Not sure why you'd need it as `newSubItem` is also defined on that same scope

Comment: Is the scope not available to a function being called on the controller? I'm not disagreeing with you but I am wondering why you would pass it as a parameter?

Comment: That's what I'm saying; there's no *obvious* reason to pass it as a parameter

Comment: Perhaps it's designed to allow passing in different scopes if required. See https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree/blob/master/examples/js/basic-example.js#L19

Comment: it's the current scope, but you need to realize that tree-view is generated using recursion. And then, each level has acessors at scope object to allow to include new nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, In here `this` refers to the scope and it will include every variable, functions which inside of it.

Wherever we use this, it will always return scope.

Here, I am passing this from parent and child, but both shows same output as `$SCOPE`

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">

  <div><a ng-click="aClick(this)">Click a</a>
    <div>
      <a ng-click="bClick(this)">Click b</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  {{aValue}} {{bValue}}
</body>
```

Please find the working plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/IdXB1ZtXMpFS3soxcBIz?p=preview